# Am I a sea lion?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[I've been told](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29067/will-the-skas-total-bandwidth-still-exceed-the-earths-internets-bandwidth/29074?noredirect=1#comment52176_29074) that I am sealioning.

From my perspective [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29074/7982) is general screen shots and a bit of block quoted text tangentially related to the topic, but in no way addresses the question. The last line:

> Nothing will flow to [/dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device).

makes no sense at all to me at least.

I first added the comment:

> I don't see your math. These are just pasted images. There will ultimately be 7,000 SKA-mid dishes, and each dish will have its own fiber. Have you calculated that?

and then after ~five days with no improvement, I voted to delete and left a second comment:

> Question asks for a comparison of two numbers and asks which is larger. That wasn't even attempted here. I'm voting for this to be deleted as it doesn't attempt to answer the question.

I was told:

> The comments, that were deleted to clean up your question, addressed that. Now you are Sealioning. You've done that previously and I've complained about it directly to you, thinking that you might have changed I elected to give you another chance. Vote or flag as you wish.

Am I really [sealioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealioning) here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't say that I'm particularly familiar with the concept and practice of sealioning, but from what I can tell, no, your comments were not unreasonable. They seem to me to be sincere enough, and they're not rude. Your comments appeared constructive to me - and I hope that most folks can agree on that. Asking for clarification on an answer is never inappropriate.

I suppose I can see how Rob *might* have been a bit annoyed by the situation (and I'd absolutely welcome his perspective on the matter), perhaps partly by the edit/rollback disagreement between the two of you. Also, I can see how your second comment could have come across as a bit harsh or even brusque ("That wasn't even attempted here" does stand out to me), and I wonder if alternate wordings might have been better. That said, again, as I understand the definition of "sealioning", I don't believe this is an example.

As for the answer itself . . . well, as I wrote in [a comment of my own](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29067/will-the-skas-total-bandwidth-still-exceed-the-earths-internets-bandwidth/29074#comment52180_29074), I believe it would strongly benefit from the deletion of much of the copied (though I believe quite properly attributed) images and text. The right answer to your question might be buried in there, buuuuut . . . well, it's *buried*, and I'm not sure it's even there. Perhaps this is a stylistic view on my part - while I used to quote sources a lot, now I *rarely* do - but the fact that you also couldn't see an answer in it might be telling.

The comments Rob wrote (and subsequently deleted, and referenced in *their* recent comment) do seem to have held some relevant information, I would recommend that they include that information in their answer, if they can.

I've deleted the comments (the ones you quote in your question) below the answer that called out specific behavior; they're not really serving any purpose, and one was a bit belligerent/rude. I've also written a comment asking people to drop the matter, and suggesting that Rob edit the answer. If not, it might end up deleted.